# In Lua, How to use zlib decompression on a prevoiusly compressed message?

Tags: lua, zlib, compression, lua-alien

I am writing a Wireshark dissector in Lua.  The application being dissected runs over TCP.  The problem I am having is that it requires zlib decompression.  I need to decompress the data only. The data I receive has been compressed before being sent so I don't have the original uncompressed file size.  All the examples that I have tried or found require compression then decompression on the same end.   I have been trying to do this using the alien ffi.  Does anyone know how to get around this? Or can anyone help me rewrite the inflate function in zlib to work with alien?  I am including the link to the code I am currently trying to make function.  http://www.cprogramdevelop.com/3987529/

Comment: That code is using the original length to size the buffer that will be written into. If you don't have that information then you get to guess at the size and handle the resulting "not enough space" error you will get back from zlib if you under allocated.

Comment: Yeah, I tried setting it to 2*the input length.  However, I keep getting a Data_Error code (-3) when trying to do the decompression.

Comment: According to the header file I am looking at `-3` is `Z_DATA_ERROR` which means the input data was corrupted/incorrect. Are you sure you are giving it the right (and complete) data?